# PHP IF ELSE statement Issue

Tags: php

My If Statement Inside of my while loop Does not seem to Execute Properly. I think It might have something to do with my logic. To me, it seems like it should work but there must be something Im missing. I need the While loop to run and count each time it does. On the fourth loop, I need the code in the if statement to run but that never seems to happen. Can anyone offer a soloution please?

```
<?php
    $input = $_GET['input'];//Note to self $input in the name of the search feild
    $terms = explode(" ", $input);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE ";

    foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;
        if ($i == 1)
            $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        else
            $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }

    // connecting to our mysql database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    mysql_select_db("database");

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows > 0){
        for($i=0; $i < $numrows; $i++){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $keywords = $row['keywords'];
            $link = $row['link'];
            $plink = $row ['plink'];
            $views = $row ['views'];

                if($i== 4){
            echo '<td valign="top" "width="248" height="100%">
            <table width="100%" border="0">
             <tr>
                 <td align="center" valign="top"><a href='.$link.'>
                 <img src='.$plink.'width="200" height="151" vspace="5" />
            <br><b><a href='.$link.'>'.$title.'</b></a>
              <br><strong><span style="line-height:20px">Total views: '.$views.'</span></strong>
                 </td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                 </td><tr>';            
            }

            else{

            echo '<td valign="top" "width="248" height="100%">
            <table width="100%" border="0">
             <tr>
                 <td align="center" valign="top"><a href='.$link.'>
                 <img src='.$plink.'width="200" height="151" vspace="5" />
            <br><b><a href='.$link.'>'.$title.'</b></a>
              <br><strong><span style="line-height:20px">Total views: '.$views.'</span></strong>
                 </td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>'
                           ;

                }
                     }


        }



        }

    else
        echo "No results found for \"<b>$input</b>\"";



    // disconnect
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Your application is vulnerable to SQL injections...

Comment: really, how do I fix that?

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for that, you need to escape all the input that comes from outside your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping once for each row, but within your for loop, you have a while that is fetching all the rows. You need to get rid of the for loop.
So instead of doing this:

```
    for($i=0; $i < $numrows; $i++){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
```

you should do this:

```
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $i++;
        ....
```

Comment: I f*cking Love you buddy. That was the problem. Much love and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration of your `for` loop `$i` == 1, so your condition won't execute. However, your while loop will empty the result set so that on the second and subsequent iterations of your `for` loop there are no rows to fetch. Your `if` condition isn't encountered again.